# ByBit API - Using account percentage in Qty size of position

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, trading, cryptocurrency

Please see reference here: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/futuresV2/linear/?python--pybit#order-type-order_type

```
{
    "topic": "order",
    "action": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "order_id": "19a8cbbe-e077-42c7-bdba-505c76619ea5",
            "order_link_id": "Bactive004",
            "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
            "side": "Sell",
            "order_type": "Market",
            "price": 19185.5,
            "qty": 0.01,
            "leaves_qty": 0,
            "last_exec_price": 20196,
            "cum_exec_qty": 0.01,
            "cum_exec_value": 201.95999,
            "cum_exec_fee": 0.121176,
            "time_in_force": "ImmediateOrCancel",
            "create_type": "CreateByUser",
            "cancel_type": "UNKNOWN",
            "order_status": "Filled",
            "take_profit": 0,
            "stop_loss": 0,
            "trailing_stop": 0,
            "create_time": "2022-06-23T04:08:47.956636888Z",
            "update_time": "2022-06-23T04:08:47.960908408Z",
            "reduce_only": true,
            "close_on_trigger": false,
            "position_idx": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a Python webhook script working well to trigger market orders, however I can't seem to figure out how to use 100% of the trading account for the positions triggered rather than indicating the size of the position in terms of a number. Notice the "qty" field. I tried using a percentage instead but it did not work.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Using pybit you can query your free balance in USDT then calculate the amount of coin you want to enter a position with based on your risk tolerances.

```
r = session_auth.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT") 
free = r['result']['USDT']['available_balance']
risk = 0.01
size = (free * risk) / price)
```

For example 1000 USDT of free balance, using 0.01 as 1% risk leaves you with 10 USDT to use. From there you can calculate the qty by dividing that by the price, you'll need to get the current price from another query.

```
def fetch_price(timestamp):
    data = session.auth.query_kline(
           symbol="BTCUSDT",
           interval=1,
           limit=2,
           from_time=timestamp
    )
    price = data["result"][0]["last_price"]
    return price
```

Simple description but hope that helps.